# Compare a cell to a list of other values. Higher or lower

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a list of test results in the cells of a column
I would like to find a way to show how A1 compares to all of the other cells.
In other words, the result of a test in A1 is higher than 75% of the other other results.
Can someone help with the formula?

Comment: I've figured out how to compare the cells using the MIN feature.
I now have a column that shows the comparison and I've gone thru and made the cells green where A1 is a higher result. Now if I could just figure out how to find the percentage of green cells I think I would have the results Im looking for

Comment: please post some sample data with desired results, that would help us to better understand your problem. Also please don't add new information in comments, but edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=COUNTIF(I:I,"<" & A1)/COUNT(I:I)
```

With a % format applied.  We count the total number of items less than **A1** in column **I** and divide by the total number of items in column **I**:

[image]

In the example above, the value in **A1** *(11)* is larger than 5 of the 8 items in column **I**.

Answer (score 1):

Excel has a `PERCENTILE()` function and also a `PERCENTRANK()` function.  The 75th percentile is calculated in D2 of the table below with this formula:

`=PERCENTILE(B2:B13,0.75)`

And percent ranks can be calculated in Column C with:

`=PERCENTRANK(B$2:B$13,B2)`

Finally, you can use a Conditional Formatting rule like this one to highlight those scores that are greater than 75% of all the scores:

`=$B2>PERCENTILE($B$2:$B$13,0.75)`

[image]

Comment: Names shamelessly stolen from @Gary'sStudent.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

*With a different approach, this formula will extract all values which are greater  than 75% of all.*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$8, SMALL(IF(($C$2<$B$2:$B$8), ROW($B$2:$B$2)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$2))+1, ""),ROWS($A$1:A1)), 2),"")
```

Cell C2 has 75 (the benchmark).

**Edited Part:**

[image]

In C2 write this formula.

`=QUARTILE.INC(B2:B8,3)`

*Here 3 is for 75%*

In D2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$8, SMALL(IF(($C$2<$B$2:$B$8), ROW($B$2:$B$2)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$2))+1, ""),ROWS($A$1:A1)), 2),"")
```

Comment: OP asked to show whether A1 is greater than 75 **percent** of all the other cells, not whether it's greater than the number 75.

Comment: You mean to say OP needs formula to find how may test results are higher than 75 Percentile of of A1? If yes, in this case I need to count 75 Percentile of data range  in C2 and find the higher values as you did. In that case also my formula will work :-)

Comment: My data range is B2:B7 & values are 68,75,76,92,87,70 and 75 percentile of the range in C2 is 84.25 (as you calculated), then I applies the same formula as you did to highlight values, the values I got are 92 & 87. And then I tried the same, my formula also extracts 92 & 87. My mistake was that in my answer I should have write  "Cell C2 has 75 Percentile of the data range the benchmark".

Comment: Good, then edit your answer and make it correct. It is incorrect now. Include an explanation of how to calculate the 75th percentile.